# Android - Refresh ListView before HTTP Request

Tags: android, listview, refresh

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    switch (requestCode)
    {
    case REQUEST_VOICE:
        if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) break;
        ArrayList<String> raw = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
        dialogAdapter.add(raw.get(0));
        dialogAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // Doesn't work?!
        String res = "http://192.168.0.197/xyz.php?v=1";
        res = getFromUrl(res); // Get content from internet
        if (!res.startsWith("{")) res = "Error.";
        else {
            try {
                JSONObject json = new JSONObject(res);
                dialog.set(dialog.lastIndexOf(raw.get(0)), json.getString("in")); // Should update the row that was added before the call of getFromUrl()
                res = json.getString("out");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                res = "Error";
            }
        }
        dialogAdapter.add(res);
        dialogAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // Works?
        break;
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

(I've shortened the code above.)
The ListView (dialogAdapter is the adapter) will refresh after the function (onActivityResult) is fully executed,
but I want to append a row to it before I call getFromUrl().

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is working fine as it expected

The problem which occurs here is you application execution continues till here..

```
dialogAdapter.add(raw.get(0));
dialogAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // Doesn't work?!
```

actually it works but you are calling another task which hangs the UI thread, here it is:

```
res = getFromUrl(res);
```

It hangs the UI thread to update itself, and after the data has been fetched 
this line executed again.

```
dialogAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // Works?
```

and ListView updated.

Solutino: Never perform URL request on UI thread. Use `AsyncTask`